# How to set up Ubuntu to less easily make full-width/half-width number mistakes?

Tags: firefox, fonts, japanese, mozc

In Japanese, numbers can be written either full-width or half-width:

- Full-width: １２３４５６７８９０
- Half-width: 1234567890

Nowadays in my field everyone use half-width, and using full-width is seen as a gross lack of professionalism. Unfortunately Ubuntu makes it easy to mix up full-width and half-width.

Some programs make the distinction very clear, for instance `vi`:
[image]

... but other programs (most importantly `firefox`) make almost no distinction:

[image]

That leads to very incompetent-looking messages. When the customers look at the message above in their Mac browsers the distinction is super-clear.

## Question

How to set up Ubuntu to make it much more difficult to mistakenly type full-width numbers?

I am not sure what is the root problem, but I can imagine two strategies:

- Prevent programs from using fonts that do not make the distinction clear enough.
- Modify the input method to never input full-width numbers.

I have no idea how to implement these strategies though. Other strategies are also very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The full-width characters are typed only when you attempt to input 2-byte characters, which are mostly Asian languages, I think.

This is an example how you avoid to type in a full-width characters, especially numbers.

[image]

This is a mozc configuration panel; advanced tab from which is brought by this way.

[image]

There're many other input methods and should be set by different ways but almost always the same, e.g. Anthy or ATOK, Windows IME and etc.

---

The other way to force full-width numbers replaced into half-width, when your text file probably contains some mixed full- and half-width numbers.

```
sed 'y/０１２３４５６７８９/0123456789/'
```

For example, you have an uncertain *text1* file looks like:
12123
１５３２
４５６

And you want to replace all the full-width numbers into half-width numbers and create a new file *text2*

```
cat text1 | sed 'y/０１２３４５６７８９/0123456789/' > text2
```

You get:
12123
1532
456

ps. You can also replace full-width alphabet letters into half-width, that would be:

```
sed 'y/０１２３４５６７８９ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ/0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/'
```